# What does Hinduism say about married women taking care of her parents?

Tags: dharma, women, parents

Traditionally in society, married women are expected to "take care" of their husband, in-laws and husband's family.

What does Sanatana Dharma (Hinduism) say about women taking care of her elderly parents when she doesn't have any brothers? Are there any such examples where women have taken care of their aging parents?

Or is Sanatana Dharma so cruel to let the parents of a girl suffer on their own in their old age simply because they couldn't procreate a male child?